# C# Bitmap dispose memory usage

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, garbage-collection

I'm currently implementing webcam functionality into an app I'm creating however I've had some issues with memory usage.

My function is as shown below

This is the first implementation

```
private void webcam_newFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) {
    if (!_pause) {
        var img = (Bitmap) eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pbPicture.BackgroundImage = img;            
    }
}
```

However this code caused huge memory leaks, running up 2gb (of ram I assume). Before crashing due to out of memory.
I then changed the code to dispose of the Bitmap, like so

```
private void webcam_newFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) {
    if (!_pause) {
        var img = (Bitmap) eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pbPicture.BackgroundImage = img;
        img.Dispose(); // This causes exception
    }
}
```

This causes Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll.

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

On the following code which calls this form to be shown:

```
WebcamForm wForm = new WebcamForm();
wForm.ShowDialog();
```

So I then changed the function to this:

```
private void webcam_newFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) {
    if (!_pause) {
        pbPicture.BackgroundImage = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

This code works correctly, memory usage stays around 360mb which is consistent and a reasonable figure considering the application.

My question is, is forcing a garbage collection on every frame a good solution to this? Are there any potential issues?

I'm sure I've seen answers in the past that forcing garbage collection is a bad thing to do, however I can't think of any alternative ways around this problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispose the old value of BackgroundImage, not the new value you are passing in.

```
private void webcam_newFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) {
    if (!_pause) {
        var img = (Bitmap) eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        var oldImg =  pbPicture.BackgroundImage;
        pbPicture.BackgroundImage = img;
        oldImg?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for this, however it reverts back to throwing the System.ArgumentException in System.Drawing.dll error as detailed in my original question. I believe it's caused by disposing the Bitmap as I don't get that error when using the implementation of GC.Collect(). I can't get visual studio to break properly to debug, so I don't know how to narrow it down any further

Comment: Okay ignore that, using PictureBox.Image rather than PictureBox.BackgroundImage fixes that issue. Not sure why it would make a difference but it's a solution

Answer (score 1):

Calling often the garbage collector is a bad practice.

Try to dispose the old bitmap after the newone.

```
private void webcam_newFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) {
  if (!_pause) {
      Bitmap oldBitmap = (Bitmap)pbPicture.BackgroundImage;
      pbPicture.BackgroundImage = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
      oldBitmap.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful, if there is no default background image your code will throw a null reference exception on the first call.